How to resolve 'Cannot find module './warning_messages.json''
I'm not able to run my node in NodeJs.
Facing this issue:
PS D:\PristineAIOPS\PristineAIOPS> npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module './warning_messages.json'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\make_warning.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\lib\read-json.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetcher.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\index.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\cache.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\rberbato\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-15T14_02_30_582Z-debug-0.log

I tried to reinstall NodeJS and remove node_modules but still not able to bypass this error.

you need to make sure that the warning_messages.json file is within your current working directory, the error is stating that it cannot be found, it cannot resolve it.
this problem can be solved by either:

moving the warning_messages.json file to your current working directory
instead of using the relative path ex. ./warning_messages.json you can pass the absolute path of the file ex. C:\Users\{User}\desktop\{current-working-directory}\warning_messages.json

